# VisualEffectView in Swift and Xcode9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9, swift4

[Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgnty.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var addItemView: UIView!

   @IBOutlet weak var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!

   var effect: UIVisualEffect!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        effect = visualEffectView.effect
        visualEffectView.effect = nil

        addItemView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
   }

    func animateIn(){
        self.view.addSubview(addItemView)
        addItemView.center = self.view.center

        addItemView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        addItemView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4){
            self.visualEffectView.effect = self.effect
            self.addItemView.alpha = 1
            self.addItemView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sourcesButton(_ sender: Any) {
        animateIn()
    }


    @IBAction func sourceDone(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I am trying to make a blurry modal that pops up when the user clicks a button, but for some reason this code is not executing. I was following a tutorial on youtube [(Youtube Link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXvOS6hYADc&t=605s) I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to post your code here so that readers can offer advice. Always post your attempt at the code when you ask a question

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: There you go! LOoks like a pro question now. Welcome aboard

Answer (score 1):

Create blur view like this instead:

```
var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
var blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

And after it is created you can set alpha to 0 and animate it to 1.
Please note that animation with UIBlurEffect looks horrible on the device :p